# White Screen after renaming files

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Let's assume the following: I have a class based component Foo and it's saved under Foo.js. If I want to rename the component and its file to another name, the builds for android & iOS succeed but I get a white screen. I also edited all import where the old file name/class was referenced.

I also tried the following, but without any success:

- sudo rm -rf ./node_modules
- watchman watch-del-all
- npm install
- uninstall the app, reinstall again

Any suggestions how I can get rid of this white screen?

Comment: Make sure all places that import that component are referencing the correct file/component name

Comment: You don't get any error if you try to log it?

Comment: Nope. Not an error. Nothing. Debugging is disabled, so that's definitely not it.